# Is it ok to prove a subset of a group is an abelian group this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I'll admit from the start I'm being lazy, but all the same it makes thing's neater in my opinion - if it's valid.

Now it's known that if we have a group $G$ such that $g^2=e,\ \ \forall g \in G$ then $G$ is abelian. But what if we don't know G is a group yet? We know the mentioned condition, but thats it. Is it ok to just check, say $x,y \in G \implies xy \in G$ and take the other order for granted? Since.. well, the group, if it is one, will be abelian!

In particular, I'd like to show that $G=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}\subset S_4$ is an abelian group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As every element has order two you do not need to check both directions of every multiplication, i.e., you have $3$ non-identity elements and you only need to check $\binom32 = 3$ multiplications instead of the $6$ that a brute force approach would normally require.

The reason is because if $xy = z$ and $z$ is in your subset, then because $z$ has order two we know that $z^{-1} = z$ is in your subset, and $z^{-1} = (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} = yx$ (because $x$ and $y$ also have order $2$).

That trick I just used is exactly how you prove that if every element of a group is order $2$ it is abelian, but I don't want to say that it's because of that theorem that you don't have to check the other multiplications.  Really it's because of the **proof** of that theorem; because the method of proof still applies in this circumstance.  I make this distinction because if you have a theorem that says "If a group satisfies condition $P$ then that group is a $Q$" and then you check that a *subset* satisfies condition $P$, then in general it is **NOT** true that this implies that your *subset* is in fact a *subgroup* of type $Q$.

Comment: +1: Nice observation. However, we only need to check **one** multiplication, not three (and not two, as I mistakenly surmised earlier). If you can show that $ab=c,$ then right-multiplying by $b$ and left-multiplying by $c$ immediately yields $ca=b$ (since $b^2=c^2=e$). From there, left-multiplying by $b$ and right-multiplying by $a$ gives you $bc=a.$ At that point, your trick implies that $ba=c,$ $ac=b,$ and $cb=a.$ A single check, then, is enough to prove both closure and abelianness, once these tricks are observed.

Answer (score 2):

When taking arbitrary elements $x, y \in G$ to test for closure (to test whether $x, y \in G \implies xy \in G$), then the order of the product doesn't matter.

That is, if you can show $xy \in G$ in that situation, then you've proven closure of the candidate group under the group operation *regardless* of whether the candidate group is abelian or not. So it is never necessary to show, *additionally,* that $yx \in G$ when trying to establish that $G$ is closed.

UPDATE: Given your clarification about the specific set in question:

As you note, we know only that a *subgroup* (*group*) with every element of order two is abelian. In order to conclude that your set is therefore abelian, we need first to establish that the proposed set **is** a subgroup (group) of $S_4$. Then once that's done, you can conclude it must be abelian, based on your knowledge of groups whose elements are all of order $2$.

Comment: I can't talk about elements og G arbitrarily though.. Specifically I'm concerned with $\{e,(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\} \subset S_4$

Comment: Well, in this case, we only know that a *subgroup* or group with all elements of order two is abelian. We need first to establish that the proposed set **is** a subgroup of $S_4$. Then once that's done, you can conclude it must be abelian, based on your knowledge of groups whose elements are all of order $2$.

Comment: @FireGarden: The nice thing, here, is that you've already got identity and inverses (since every element has order at most $2$). The only thing you've got to check is closure, and there are at most $3$ multiplications to check.

Comment: @CameronBuie So.. I was right? Essentially I know ab=c, and I wanted to say "since we know G will have to be abelian, then ba=c" and only check three multiplications..

Comment: @CameronBuie: See my answer